# How to shout in Skyrim on the Switch?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, nintendo-switch

I have killed three dragons and it is equipped to my <kbd>ZL</kbd> button. Every time I press <kbd>ZL</kbd>, it just punches people though. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to shout for the Greybeards and it won't let me. Please just give me step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Did you "equipped" the shout (judging by that situation I think you're trying to use Fus Ro Dah; Unrelenting Force)? You have to equip the shout at magic menu before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Under the *default* controls, Dragon Shouts (and other Powers) are assigned to the <kbd>R</kbd> button.

<kbd>zL</kbd> is to use your off-hand (left hand weapon/spell, or block with shield)

<kbd>zR</kbd> is to use your main-hand (right hand weapon/spell)

Powers and Dragon Shouts do not count as normal Magic Spells; they do not use your hands to cast.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/399787/4797) stating that you need to press the <kbd>R</kbd> button, you of course need to as well equip the shout you want to use in case you have not done this already.

The shout is equipped aside from your normal left and right-hand item and is because of that, linked to the <kbd>R</kbd> button.

I am mentioning this as this was my mistake in the past and know that the tutorial can be unclear.

[image: controls]

<sup>Screenshot source: https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Controls_(Skyrim)</sup>